# How to create a Clob with Entity Manager needed to call a stored procedure in an Oracle database?

Tags: java, oracle, entitymanager

I am trying to call an Oracle stored procedure, which has a Clob for an input argument. I am using EntityManager for our DB connection. I do not know how to initialize the Clob variable (look the code below).

This is our code:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "oracledb")
private EntityManager entityManager;

....

StoredProcedureQuery query =
    entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("procedure1");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, Clob.class, ParameterMode.IN);

query.setParameter(1, data1);
query.setParameter(2, data2);

Clob clob //<---how to initialize this CLOB???
clob.setString(1, data3);
query.setParameter(3, clob);

query.execute();
```

How do I initialize the Clob or how do I get the connection from EntityManager so I can call

```
connection.createClob()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using hibernate you can create a Clob easily:

```
String data3 = "whatever";
Clob clob = org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.NonContextualLobCreator.INSTANCE.createClob( data3 );
```